# Define a function using string variable

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function "a21" that takes a parameter x and adds 4 to it.

```
eq = 'x+4'
b=21
new='a'+str(b)+'(x)'
def eval(new):
    return eval(eq)

c=5
print(a21(c))
```

The desired output is 9 but it's not recognizing a21 as a function. How do I write this to create a the function a21 that also takes a parameter x?

Comment: `def eval(new): return eval(eq)` will result in infinite recursion

Comment: `eval` can be dangerous, and should generally only be used as a last resort when there are no other options. [What are you _really_ trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Looks like you are generally asking for something like SymPy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a fully-featured function definition:

```
new = '''
def a21(x):
    return x + 4
'''
```

And then `exec`ute it: `exec(new)` and run: `a21(678)`.

If you want to construct a function during runtime, use string formatting.

```
new = '''
def {}({}):
    return {}
'''

exec(new.format('test', 'x', 'x+4'))

test(123)
```

Comment: You need `exec` to execute a statement like `def`; `eval` only evaluates expressions.

Comment: @chepner, yeah, you're right, I'm gonna edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

The following is possible and does almost the same thing:
You can bind the function in a function like below.

```
eq = 'x+4'
def bindfunc(name):
  def dynamicfunc(x):
    return eval(eq)
  dynamicfunc.__name__ = name
  return dynamicfunc
```

The way you would use this would be a little different:

```
b=21
new='a'+str(b) #your function name
c=5
print(bindfunc(new)(c))
```

What the last line does is that it first runs bindfunc which returns a function with the given name. It then runs that function with the input c as needed and prints output.

Hope this helps!